# Honda dealership questionable maintenance

Tags: honda, maintenance, service

My 2009 CRV with 59,500 miles and absolutely no problems went in for the 60,000 service.  I was called and told that my power steering fluid smelled burned and looked dark.  I was told that I needed a flush and new fluid.  I have a knowledgible friend who tells me that this is bogus.  He said that if it were indeed burnt smelling, then something else was the cause (under warranty hopefully).  He also said that my CRV should probably never need new power steering fluid.   They also dinged me for a flush and new fluid for my brakes as well.

Comment: Well, for starters, brake fluid is hygroscopic and depending on what your local climate is like, needs to be changed on an annual or bi-annual basis to maintain proper brake performance.

Answer (score 6):

Power steering fluid breaks down over time and needs to be replaced every so often, similar to your brake fluid or most other fluids in your car for that matter. I think that you’re being a little too incredulous of the dealership, and maybe your friend isn’t so knowledgeable, or there was just a misunderstanding.

The point is: yes, power steering fluid and brake fluid (as Timo mentioned) should be changed regularly to prevent wear and tear.